# BEM multiple classes selector

Tags: css, bem

I am trying to follow the BEM naming convention and I am unsure how to implement the following: I have a "tooltip" block which should be styled with different themes. Let's say I apply a "default" theme.

```
<div class="tooltip tooltip_theme_default"></div>
```

The tooltip can be placed around an element in different positions, this sounds to me like I have to add a "horizontal-position" and a "vertical-position" modifier to the block.

```
<div class="tooltip tooltip_theme_default tooltip_horizontal-position_center tooltip_vertical-position_top"></div>
```

Now I need to display a decoration on the tooltip, depending both on the theme and its position. I think I need a multiple class selector, but I can't see any examples of multiple selector like this on the BEM documentation.

```
.tooltip_theme_default.tooltip_horizontal-position_center.tooltip_vertical-position_top::before {
     /* styles */
 }
```

Is that allowed by the BEM specification?
Can you think of any drawbacks?
Should I try to rethink my component to use just flat classes selectors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although BEM advises to avoid multiple class selectors, in your case it is just fine. You may use [bem-components library](https://en.bem.info/libs/bem-components/) as a source of examples. E.g. https://github.com/bem/bem-components/blob/v2/design/common.blocks/popup/_theme/popup_theme_islands.styl#L22

Comment: I am just experimenting for the first time with BEM, I am trying to understand if it can be good for larger adoption in my company, but honestly I am surprised that the first component I am trying to implement already requires to "break" the convention. It seems to me a really strict framework. Since you claim to be addicted to it, I'd like to hear your opinion, maybe in http://chat.stackoverflow.com/ ?

Comment: I'd better invite you to our forum at https://en.bem.info/forum/ (auth via github). Will do my best to help.